# Question Regarding a Group G

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and let $a,b  \ \epsilon \ G.$ Show that $(a * b) * (a' * b') = e$ if and only if $(a * b)$ =  $(b * a)$

Note that * is a binary operation, $a'$ and $b'$ are inverses of $a$ and $b$.

Solutions, first steps, and/or hints welcome.

Comment: Sure $\ast$ is the group operation and not some arbitrary binary operation?

Comment: My word choice was poor you are correct

Comment: Given the first equation, how can we manipulate it to get $b \ast a$ on the RHS as in the second equation.

Comment: Just use associativity. Multiply LHS for $b*a$ abd see what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not difficult. Let's do the first direction and I'll leave you to do the converse.(Remember, iff means you have to prove the statement in **both directions**-you'd be surprised how many beginners don't really get that although they think they do!)

Assume (1) (a*b)*(a'*b') = e. Then by definition, 
     (2) (a'*b') = (a*b)'. 
    Remove the parentheses, remembering general associativity in the orders of operation. Multiply on the right by b: 
     (3) aba'b'= e ---->  aba'(b'b)= eb --->   aba'e= b ---? aba' = b.

Then multiply on the right a second time by a: 
      (4) (aba')a = ba  ab(a'a)= ba ----> abe = ba ---> ab= ba

Which is exactly what we wanted to prove. Q.E.D.

(Btw, I originally got confused by the problem and wasted an hour because I thought it said (a*b) (a*b)=e -which is a completely different problem. I really need to get new glasses,seriously............. : ( )